# Why is MongoDB slow inserting data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm trying to save the parsed data into MongoDB. I want to store every referrer URL. At present it is taking a lot of time to insert into MongoDB.

```
  class ReferrerDocument
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :website_url, String
    key :referrer_url, String
    key :full_referrer_url, String
    key :count_of_appearance, Integer, :default => 1
    key :current_time, Time
    timestamps!

    def self.save_referrer_info(website_url, referrer_url, full_referrer_url, current_time)
      referrer_document = ReferrerDocument.last(:website_url => website_url,
                                                :referrer_url => referrer_url,
                                                :order => :id.asc)
      if(referrer_document.nil?)
        ReferrerDocument.create(:website_url => website_url,
                                :referrer_url => referrer_url,
                                :full_referrer_url => full_referrer_url,
                                :last_seen_at => 0,
                                :current_time => current_time)
      else
        count = referrer_document.count_of_appearance += 1
        last_seen_at = referrer_document.current_time.utc
        ReferrerDocument.create(:website_url => website_url,
                                :referrer_url => referrer_url,
                                :full_referrer_url => full_referrer_url,
                                :last_seen_at => last_seen_at,
                                :current_time => current_time,
                                :count_of_appearance => count)
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to actually measure how long each part takes to execute?

From what I see, the only place that could possibly be slow is `ReferrerDocument.last` invocation.

How many documents you have in this collection? Do you have supporting indexes?
What mongodb query does `ReferrerDocument.last` translate to (you can see in development.log. I myself am a [mongoid](http://mongoid.org) user)?
What does explain plan for this query look like?

To make this query most efficient you'll need an index on `{website_url: 1, referrer_url: 1, _id: 1}`